# Why is my component not loading through Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am building a React project with Vite. I was using a tutorial from an article that I found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-react-project-with-vite.

I followed the tutorial as described, however, my "greeting" component will not load.

```
import React from 'react';

function greeting() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
}

export default greeting;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import greeting from "./greeting";


function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      React⚛️ + Vite⚡ + Replit
      <greeting />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const container = document.getElementById("root");

const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components should start with capital letter .

```
import React from 'react';

function Greeting() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  );
}

export default Greeting;




import React from 'react';
import Greeting from "./greeting";


function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      React⚛️ + Vite⚡ + Replit
      <Greeting />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

React components have to start with a capital letter, or they will be compiled to a plain HTML tag.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized
So your greeting function should be named `Greeting`, and change the tag in `App()` to `<Greeting />`

Answer (score 0):

your component import name should use Capital Letter

ex : import Greeting from "./greeting";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).